# object oriented getter and setter?

Tags: c#, oop

I wrote an absolutely simple code in C# and ran into a ridiculous problem!

I have a class name order and there is a field declared such as:

```
private int[] pizzano = new int[8];
public void setPizzaNo(int[] pno)
{
    pizzano = pno;
}
public int[] getPizzano()
{
    return pizzano;
}
```

I get an object and set it in another class like this:

```
order order = new order();
order.setPizzaNo(pizzano);
```

`pizzano` is an array of integer which I assign different values to, but when I use the `get` method, it just returns zero values. I got crazy and can't understand what my problem is!

Comment: You're writing Java in C#. In C#, [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) are a first class concept.

Comment: how are you creating pizzano for setPizzaNo?

Comment: The code you wrote is not very c# but seems correct. Can you provide the client code that is failing?

Comment: `order order = new order(); order.setPizzaNo(pizzano);` - you should include few lines more. Show the whole method that includes these lines to provide more context.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever:Yes, actully I am java programmer, but this project in c#.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that you shouldn't write C# code using the idioms of Java (or vice versa). In C#, you write properties using a specialized syntax, and then use them in a way that closely resembles field access (e.g `order.PizzaNo = pizzano`) rather than method invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Working fine for me:-

```
public class order
{
    private int[] pizzano = new int[8];
    public void setPizzaNo(int[] pno)
    {
        pizzano = pno;
    }
    public int[] getPizzano()
    {
        return pizzano;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] pizzano = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
        order order = new order();
        order.setPizzaNo(pizzano);

        foreach (var item in order.getPizzano())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the diffrence of this code with mine is use of foreach and when I add it to my code, it answered correctly surprisingly!! I wonder what's the problem with usual for!

Answer (score 4):

A getter/setter is implemented in the c# language.

```
private int[] m_iArrPizzano = new int[];
```

You can capsulate this by doing the follows:

```
public int[] Pizzano { 
   get { 
      return m_iArrPizzano;
   }
   set {
      m_iArrPizzano = value;
   }
}
```

However, when you don't want to check for wrong sets, you can use the small version without declaring an private field.

```
public int[] Pizzano { get; set; }
```

will generate the above automatically on build.

Access it with `obj.Pizzano = new int[1] { 0 };`

Comment: In C# we usually don't prefix fields with `m`.

Comment: @DennisZiolkowski People with some C++ background used to it, so they use it. You might also see `s_StaticField`.

Comment: If you learned C# in the university the professor most like has a C++ background and no real C# background. The `iArr` that indicates an int array is also heavily discouraged in C#. It is called Hungarian notation and way outdated. It only adds clutter to the code. That's the problem with universities: They provide theoretical knowledge. If and how that can be used in actual practice is a whole different question. On the other hand, it really isn't the task of a university to teach you a good naming convention. They should teach you the concepts behind software development.

Comment: Regarding on internet research, you're totally right. Nevertheless, programming teams/companies can use their own conventions. I'll take a look at the web and look for better conventions. The hungarian notation I learned in my informatic technical assistant qualification. It's burned in.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth good comment, but I still don't understand how and why I should use m_iArr!
I had never seen it before

Comment: @Narges: In C# code: Never use constructs like `m_iArr`. Period. The "rules" regarding this should actually be identical in Java IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int[] pizzano;
public void setPizzaNo(int[] pno)
{
    pizzano = pno;
}
public int[] getPizzano()
{
    return pizzano;
}
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Order order = new Order();
    int[] pizzano = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int[] test;
    order.setPizzaNo(pizzano};
    test = order.getPizzano();
    for(int i=0; i<test.Length; i++)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(test[i]);
    }
```

Comment: `System.out.println()` - really? in c#?

Comment: from getter and setter you can easily understand it's not c#

Comment: how it is not C#? C# does not prohibit you from writing getters and setters as methods.

Comment: also it's not important what language it is. you can use echo, writeln also just for being solution oriented

Comment: I'm not sure if compiler will find lower-case `main` method, but it definitely will not like this parameter `String args[]`

Comment: `string args[]` is perfectly standard for a C# entrypoint method.

Answer (score 0):

As others wrote, your code is not C#-like, but your problem is not not caused by this.

Because you don't provide any client code, I can only suppose it depends on some other assignment you do in your client code between the **set** and the **get**.

Try to check this.

Answer (score -1):

Hey check the following code and try:

```
    int[] pizzano = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    Order order = new Order();
    order.setPizzaNo(pizzano);
    int[] getvalues = order.getPizzano(); 
    System.out.println(getvalues[1]);
```

Comment: put a for loop like
 for(int i=0;i<getvalues.length;i++){
 System.out.println(getvalues[i]);
}

Comment: This is java, not C#. Look at the tags. -1

Comment: @Leri - even though the op missed properties, it still does not explain why he gets zeroes so it might be ok to help him figure out that problem and not just point to properties which might not be the cause.

Comment: @Knaģis I don't understand how your comment is related to mine. However, OP is passing byte array with the length of 8, each item containing default value of byte (i.e. 0). What s/he gets is correct. I don't get what is asked here.

Comment: @Leri i think only difference in the code will be printing the values

Answer (score -1):

pizzano is private, you cannot return a private member with a simple method.

You need to use get and set

```
private int[] pizzano;
    public int[] PizzaNo 
    {
        get { return (pizzano); }
        set { pizzano = value; }
    }
```

Comment: this is false. every class member (method or property) will be able to access private members. that `pizzano` he is using to pass to the setter is a different variable.

Comment: @Luca 1. What do you mean by _simple method_? 2. Yes, you **can** return private member inside class.

Comment: @Leri inside the same class, he is is using a method as accessor, but it cannot return a private member outside the "owner" class

Comment: @Luca There's not even a hint that OP tries to return private member outside of a class.

Comment: @Leri quoting : "I get an object and set it in [another] class like this:

order order = new order();
order.setPizzaNo(pizzano);

pizzano is an array of integer which I assign different values to, but when I use the [get]"